# How to disconnect a Wifi connection instead of using "forget" connection

Tags: wi-fi

Suppose I want to disconnect to Wifi connection 'A' so that I can connect to Wifi connection 'B', how do I go into doing it without using the "Forget" connection for Wifi connection 'A'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple way to achieve this.

we have two cases in our hands.

**Case A:** When The `Wifi connection 'B'` is already in the Remembered (Saved) List in your Device, then you have to just Open the Wifi -> Just Click on the `Wifi Connection 'B'` from the list. and it will automatically get connected to it.

**Case B:** When The `Wifi connection 'B'` isn't already in the Remembered(Saved) List in your Device, then Open the Wifi -> Just Click on the `Wifi Connection 'B'` from the list, and you will be asked for the password and then If the Signing process goes well. you are now connected to the `Wifi connection 'B'`.

Hope this helps you.

**Izzy's note**:  Whenever you connect to WiFi B while a connection to A is active, the latter connection will be cancelled (disconnected) automatically as there only can be one WiFi connection active.

Comment: Background: whenever you connect to WiFi B while a connection to A is active, the latter connection will be canceled (disconnected) automatically as there only can be one WiFi connection active.